# ¿Cómo establecer un array como valor a un ArrayForm en Angular?

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript

Estoy intentando establecer como valor por defecto un Array dentro multiples ArrayForm en Angular, sin embargo, no logro realizarlo correctamente.

Les muestro como se está insertando, se inserta todo el array, y solo debería de insertarse el primer valor, como se muestra en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Aquí les muestro como tengo el código

```
for (let i = 0; i < array_filt.length; i++) {
     (this.noveltyTypeForm.controls.Arraydocuments as FormArray).push(
       this.formBuilder.group({
         ArraydocumentTypes: [id_doc_array, Validators.required],
         ArraydocumentTypesRequired: [is_required_array, [Validators.required]]
       })
     );      
  }
```

Por último les muestro los array que debo de insertar como valor (aunque ya se indica en la imagen que puse de 1ra)

[2, 1, 12]
[1, 1, 0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar el índice para recorrer los arrays:

```javascript
for (let i = 0; i < array_filt.length; i++) {
  (this.noveltyTypeForm.controls.Arraydocuments as FormArray).push(
    this.formBuilder.group({
       ArraydocumentTypes: [id_doc_array[i], Validators.required],
       ArraydocumentTypesRequired: [is_required_array[i], [Validators.required]]
    })
  );      
}
```